# Reuse attribute declaration using Entity

Tags: java, xml, dtd

Following part of a dtd is not valid/working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ELEMENT root (height)>
<!ENTITY % objectPropAttr
 "min CDATA #REQUIRED
  max CDATA #REQUIRED">
<!ELEMENT height EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST height %objectPropAttr;>
]>
<!-- xml can be left out, since parser never reaches it -->
<root>
    <height min="1" max="5"/>
</root>
```

**Edit:**

I am using java to read the xml:

```
final File file = new File("file.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbFactory.setValidating(true);
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
dBuilder.parse(file);
```

**Error message:**

*Attributname must be provided in the attribute-list declaration for element "height".*

Comment: I am using java to read the file. All online validators also throw a similar message at this position.

Comment: How can the problem be reproduced? "I am using java" is too little information.

Comment: It is validated by http://www.validome.org/grammar/validate/

Comment: Updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DTD in the question consists of an [internal subset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition#Associating_DTDs_with_documents) only. This means that you cannot use parameter entity references as part of markup declarations.

It's specified in the XML 1.0 Recommendation: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#wfc-PEinInternalSubset.

This note from The Annotated XML Specification explains it clearly: http://www.xml.com/axml/notes/PEsubsets.html.

---

The entity works fine when used in an external subset (a separate file). The following XML file (root.xml),

```
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "root.dtd">
<root>
  <height min="1"/>
</root>
```

and the following DTD (root.dtd),

```
<!ELEMENT root (height+)>

<!ENTITY % objectPropAttr
 "min CDATA #REQUIRED
  max CDATA #REQUIRED">

<!ELEMENT height EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST height %objectPropAttr;>
```

produce this output when processed with [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html):

```
$ xmllint --postvalid root.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "root.dtd">
<root>
  <height min="1"/>
</root>
root.xml:3: element height: validity error : Element height does not carry attribute max
Document root.xml does not validate
```

This is as expected. If the `max` attribute is added to the XML document, the validation succeeds.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, but I do not see where your 'use-case' is related to the dtd validation error. A xml use-case was not even provided and not necessary since the dtd itself is not valid. Since `max` is required in your example your error message was predictable. I created a full xml file including the dtd (and unnecessary xml instance) and edited my question.

Comment: It was not clear from the first revision of the question that there  only was an [internal subset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition#Associating_DTDs_with_documents).